# How to make request with left join if binding field is null | MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

My current request is as below

```
SELECT t.*, cat.name AS cat_name, user.name AS user_name
FROM products AS t
LEFT JOIN category AS cat ON cat.id=t.category_id
LEFT JOIN users AS user ON user.id=t.user_id
WHERE cat.parent_id=7
```

I need to have results even if binding fields `cat.id`, `t.category_id` are `NULL`. Now in this case I have no results.

What could be workaround in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that equality (`=`) is always false when either operand is NULL. A basic solution is to explicitly test whether both values are NULL:

```
LEFT JOIN category AS cat
       ON cat.id = t.category_id
          OR (cat.id IS NULL AND t.category_id IS NULL)
```

P.S. Be kind to the next person who has to read your code (or yourself six months from now) and don't give your tables single-character aliases.

Comment: what if just one field `t.category_id` is `NULL` and other one is undefined ?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have an "undefined" type. A field either has a value or is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

try it as-

```
SELECT t.*, cat.name AS cat_name, user.name AS user_name
FROM products AS t
LEFT JOIN category AS cat ON cat.id=t.category_id and cat.parent_id=7
LEFT JOIN users AS user ON user.id=t.user_id
```